# Anyone know how can i prove that the Levi-Civita Symbol is Anti-Symmetric?

Tags: tensor-calculus

Ok so i am editing this cause it was badly written.
My definition of the Levi-Civita symbol is:

[image]

and what i wanna prove is that it is anti symmetric if i switch two out of the three indexes so basically i wanna prove that:

$ε_{ijk} = - ε_{ikj} = - ε_{jik} = - ε_{kji}$

Comment: It's *totally antisymmetric* by definition

Comment: To build on Eletie's comment, what definition of $\epsilon_{ijk}$ are you using where the antisymmetry needs to be proved?

Comment: If you don't start with a definition it is impossible to prove anything.

Comment: Ok so basically I wanna  prove that ϵijk=-ϵikj=-ϵjik=-ϵkji

Comment: You just wrote the definition.

Comment: $i,j,k$ can take on any of $3^3=27$ different values. So you have $3\times 3^3=81$ equations to check. You know all the values of epsilon, checking them shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @jacob1729 ok that was very helpful thank u very much.

Comment: I think these answers and comments which say *"it is totally antisymmetric by definition"* are completely off.  It it was antisymmetric by definition, then the definition would be "let $\epsilon_{ijk}$ be the totally antisymmetric tensor with $\epsilon_{123}=1$".  However, this is *not* the definition given in the question, so there is something to check.  The thing to check might be very trivial, but this does not mean it does not have to be checked. Similarly, if in an exam I gave a matrix $M$ element-wise and asked "Is it hermitian?", I would expect people to *check* that $M_{ij}=M_{ji}^*$.

Answer (score 2):

The Levi-Civita symbol is totally antisymmetric by definition. In fact $$\epsilon_{ijk} = 
\begin{cases}
+1 &\text{if } (i,j,k)\text{ is an even permutation of }(1,2,3)\\
-1 &\text{if } (i,j,k)\text{ is an odd permutation of }(1,2,3)\\
0 &\text{else}
\end{cases}$$

All the possibile permutations of $1,2,3$ are the following $$(1,2,3)\underset{\text{odd}}{\rightarrow}(1,3,2)\underset{\text{even}}{\rightarrow}(3,1,2)\underset{\text{odd}}{\rightarrow}(3,2,1)\underset{\text{even}}{\rightarrow}(2,3,1)\underset{\text{odd}}{\rightarrow}(2,1,3)\underset{\text{even}}{\rightarrow}(1,2,3)$$ you can easily see that by exchanging one number with the other only once, we go from an even permutation to an odd one, and viceversa. This means that by changing any two indices in the Levi-Civita symbol, you get a minus sign.

Comment: ok thx for answer and sorry i am new to tensor algebra and a bit confused.

Comment: ok sooo how do i prove that it is anti-symmetric.

ϵijk=−ϵikj=−ϵjik

Comment: @stefan.gkotsis you cannot "prove it" since it is so be definition

Comment: @DavideMorgante See my comment above. Following your logic, you couldn't prove anything which is true since it is true by definition.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you need to know is that you cannot represent $\epsilon_{ijk}$ with a $3 \times 3$ matrix. You need three $3 \times 3$ matrices to represent $\epsilon_{ijk}$ .

$\epsilon_{ijk}$  is anti-symmetric by definition. So, there is nothing to prove. however, you can show that it is anti-symmetric.

$\epsilon_{ijk} = -\epsilon_{ikj} =  -\epsilon_{jik}$

There are 3 other ways to permute the indices, try to find them and write down the correct sign.

---

answer to your edited question

In your definition you have written,

$\epsilon_{ijk} = +1 \; for\; (i,j,k)\in \{ (1,2,3) , (2,3,1) , (3,1,2) \}$

This line means  (another way of writing the same thing is ),

$\epsilon_{123} = \epsilon_{231} = \epsilon_{312} = +1 $

similarly,

$\epsilon_{ijk} = -1 \; for\; (i,j,k)\in \{ (1,3,2) , (3,2,1) , (2,1,3) \}$

means,

$\epsilon_{132} = \epsilon_{321} = \epsilon_{213} = -1 $

Comment: ok i meant 3x3x3 but basically what i wanna prove ,and cant cause it seems obvious so that can't be the correct answer ,is that its anti symmetric when i swap 2 indexes so ( basically the thing u said in your answer) . I am new to tensor algebra and this is a bit confusing sorry i am being stupid lol

Comment: There is no way to prove it. You are asking something like this. let's assume x=2, and then I want to prove that x=2! you cannot because x=2 was the assumption. it is the same story with $\epsilon_{ijk}$, we assume that it is anti-symmetric.

Comment: Ok but i have a different definition (I edited the question).I am basically agreeing with u it seems like there is nothing to prove with the definitions on other books but then i noticed we were given a different definition. Also i appreciate all the help thx

Comment: @KianMaleki No, see my comment above.